# List the customername and total quantity of products ordered for customers who have ordered less than 500 products across all their orders

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I joined three tables because there was no common record in the customers and order details table. I am not getting results, what could I be doing wrong?

[orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IguoC.png), [customerstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBlzv.png),   [orderstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V99pU.png)
This my code
    select distinct c.customername, sum(d.quantityOrdered) as totalquantity
    from orders o
    left join customers c on o.orderNumber = c.customerNumber
    left join orderdetails d on o.ordernumber = d.ordernumber
    group by c.customerNumber

The result when I run the query:
[image: The result when I run the query]

Comment: And people have asked to see some sample data, expected results and actual results (as formatted text not images).

Comment: [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @pes please do. Even though text is much better than images , either will do

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your condition from this:

```
on o.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
```

to this:

```
on o.ordernumber = d.ordernumber
```

---

Also you need to change this:

```
o.orderNumber = c.customerNumber
```

to this:

```
o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
```

---

One more thing: you should join your table orders to your table customers not other way around. That means you will need to select from `customers` and then left join table `orders` and then left join `orderdetails` on `orders`.

```
select distinct c.customername, sum(d.quantityOrdered) as totalquantity
from customers c 
left join orders o on c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
left join orderdetails d on o.ordernumber = d.ordernumber
group by c.customerNumber
having sum(d.quantityOrdered)<=500
```

Thanks Eric!

As addition to this please do check your customer join also.